# Binding a click to a div in jquery without children <a>'s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which contains some other divs inside and some `<a>`'s

I'm binding a click handler to this parent div but if u click the `<a>`'s inside this div it also triggers the handler. I tried to bind another click handler to these `<a>`'s and use `event.stopPropagation()` but that doesn't seem to work.

any ideas?

Comment: Please post the relevant code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Did you forget to pass the `event` parameter to your click handler on the `<a>`s?  Because `stopPropagation()` [seems fine](http://jsbin.com/omarij/1/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#parent *").on("click", function(e) {
    if ( e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a' ) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    ... your original code ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this.

```
$('div, a').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).is('a')) return false;
    console.log('click');
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sRfcJ/)

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the bound element to trigger the handler, put this at the top of  your handler.

```
if (this !== e.target)
    return;
```

Now the code will return immediately if any nested element was clicked. *(Don't forget to define the `e` parameter to the handler.)*

Answer (score 0):

You can check clicked element by target.nodeName

```
$("div").click(function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName == "div" $(e.target).hashClass('validDiv')){
        // do stuff
    }
     else{
       return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method is to "hijack" the click events into individual separate functions. Since the `<a>` link will be fired first, you can have that one set a boolean within the page that the `<div>` onclick checks for and simply have that one return false if it detects a previous click.

```
var linkClicked = false;

function LinkClick(something)
{
    linkClicked = true;
    // Do something
}

function DivClicked(something)
{
    if (linkClicked)
    {
        linkClicked = false;
        return false;
    }

    // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/phillipkregg/65fNS/

It's pretty basic - since I have no idea what your current code is - but I'm not seeing any problems with stopPropagation();

To experiment, if you remove the `e.stopPropagation()` you'll see that when you click a link, it fires that function first, then the div's function.